# jQuery ajax on response returns 302 error " Moved Temporarily"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using the plugin I used before many times and it returns me error. This is uploadify extended plugin "uploadifive", but that doesn't matter becouse it works I think properly but there is something strange with MVC controller i think so.

```
public function ajax()
{
    echo 'asd';
}
```

and when I go via url to `mysite.com/request/ajax/` it returns me "asd", but when I make ajax request to it, it returns me `302 Moved Temporarily` and loads main page for me. So where is the catch?

Comment: When you hit `mysite.com/request/ajax/` it is a `GET` request, does your `ajax reqeust` use same method, or `POST`? There can be different routing.

Comment: provide the ajax code you tried

Comment: Hit F12, then Network then see if you are redirected when you are in the browser

Comment: the problem was with CSRF in my website, it was enabled but the token were not sent via ajax. problem solved.